# How to convert web URL data to JSON format

Tags: android, django

I am mobile application developer. I want to try to get web URL data in JSON format. I have try to build image aggregator application.

https://yandex.com/images/search?rpt=imageview&url=https%3A%2F%2Favatars.mds.yandex.net%2Fget-images-cbir%2F1973508%2FEArWpseFrv-9jTLCuEUwTw5291%2Forig&cbir_id=1973508%2FEArWpseFrv-9jTLCuEUwTw5291

I am trying this URL data in JSON format like our REST API response. Is it possible to convert JSON data of this URL.

I have also knowledge of Django framework. If it is not possible from front end using android studio then please share me possibility of Django.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public JsonObject getJson(String url) {
    try {
        String queryString = url.split("\\?")[1];
        String[] members = queryString.split("&");

        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        for (String member : members) {
            String key = URLDecoder.decode(member.split("=")[0], "UTF-8");
            String value = URLDecoder.decode(member.split("=")[1], "UTF-8");
            json.addProperty(key, value);
        }
        return json;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```